Issues with EJS path resolution after deployment to Vercel
I'm encountering a path resolution issue with my EJS templates after deploying my Express.js application to Vercel. The application works perfectly in my local environment, but after deploying, I'm receiving errors related to missing files.
Project Directory Structure

Here’s the structure of my project:
Project (main folder)
    node_modules/ (Dependency files installed via npm)
    src/ (Main source directory)
        pages/ (Directory for EJS templates or views)
            index.ejs (Main page or template)
        public/ (Static files directory, including styles and images)
            styles.css (CSS file)
            og image.jpg (Open Graph image)
            small logo.png (Small logo image)
            large logo.png (Large logo image)
        partials/ (Directory for reusable EJS partials)
            header.ejs (Header partial)
            footer.ejs (Footer partial)
            script.ejs (Script partial)
            bootcss.ejs (Bootstrap CSS partial)
        index.js (Main application file, likely where Express.js is set up)
    nodemon.json (Configuration for Nodemon)
    .gitattributes (Git configuration file)
    .gitignore (Specifies files to ignore in Git)
    LICENSE (License for the project)
    package-lock.json (Specific version information for dependencies)
    package.json (Project configuration, including dependencies and scripts)
    README.md (Documentation for the project)
    vercel.json (Configuration for Vercel deployment)

Problem
When I deploy the application to Vercel, I receive the following error:

Error: /var/task/src/pages/index.ejs:29
    27|     <!-- Favicon -->
    28|     <link rel="icon" href="zorbis small logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
 >> 29|     <%- include ('src/partials/bootcss.ejs') %>       
    30|     </head>
    31|     <body>
    32|         <%- include ('partials/header') %>

Could not find the include file "src/partials/bootcss.ejs"
    at getIncludePath (/var/task/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:185:13)
    at includeFile (/var/task/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:311:19)
    at include (/var/task/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:701:16)
    at eval ("/var/task/src/pages/index.ejs":12:17)
    at index (/var/task/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:703:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/var/task/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:274:36)
    at exports.renderFile [as engine] (/var/task/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:609:3)


Things I've Tried
Updating Paths: Initially, I used paths like ../partials/file which worked locally but failed on Vercel. I have since changed the paths to src/partials/file but it still does not resolve the issue.
Path Formatting: I have tried including the file with and without the .ejs extension, but neither approach works on Vercel.
Directory Structure: I verified that the directory structure on Vercel matches my local setup, and all necessary files are included.
